# Laravel 5.2 : Elequent deleted_at Null/!Null with where clause and count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using eloquent to fetch some records on the basis of condition.

```
$completed = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('deleted_at', '=', !Null)->get()->count();

$incompleted = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('deleted_at', '=', Null)->get()->count();
```

The first one returns `0` which is correct.
But the second one returns `0` which should be `1` instead.

Table :

[image: Table Data]

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Do you use softDeletes? Then use Task::withTrashed in your statements.

Comment: yeah i am using soft deletes, I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: Can you share your Task model.

Comment: And you are sure your userId is '1' and not 3 or so when running the statements?

Comment: Yeah i did `dd(Auth::user()->id)`. Its `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you're using SoftDeletes in your Task model in a manner similar to this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Task extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
```

Then your queries should look like this:

```
$completed = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->onlyTrashed()->get()->count();

$incompleted = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->count();
```

The onlyTrashed method returns records where deleted_at is filled, but excludes records where deleted_at is null.

There is also a withTrashed method that returns records where deleted_at is filled along with records where deleted_at is null.

As a general rule, you should avoid querying the deleted_at column directly when using SoftDeletes and instead use the provided methods. By default all records where deleted_at is filled will be excluded.

You should also make sure you've used the softDeletes() method in your migrations so the column is correctly setup in your database.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, as you said, you're using soft deletes, you don't need to do anything special to return all non-deleted records:

```
$completed = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->get()
                 ->count(); // according to your DB screenshot this should be '3'
```

To get **only** the soft deletes, use `onlyTrashed()`:

```
$notCompleted = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->onlyTrashed()
                 ->get()
                 ->count(); // according to your DB screenshot this should be '2'
```

To get **all** records:

```
$tasks = Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->withTrashed()
                 ->get()
                 ->count(); // according to your DB screenshot this should be '5'
```

More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models